# gmock mock function that modifies input

Tags: c, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to test `func1` with google-mock and google-test

```c
int func1(){
  struct a;
  func2(&a)
  if(a.attr) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

To test `func1`, I need to test code inside `if` condition.
So, I need to make sure a.attr is True.
For that I need to mock `func2`, as it is initializing the struct.

How can I mock `func2` using google mock?
I know about `ON_CALL`, but I can't seem to mock modifications to inputs, only return values.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you want your mock function to assign a value to `a` you could use `SetArgPointee<N>(value)`. If it's more complicated you can try some `Invoke` action.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for